# Show Tag panel in custom post type | Jetengine

Tags: tags, jet-engine

actually I'm zero with coding :) but i want to know how i can have tags panel meta box in my CPT jet engines like wordpress tags panel.i searched for similar topics but didn't work for jet engine !
for ex i have "فیلم" CPT and i want to have tags panel (Meta box) to start taging but by default i haven't it !
or it is possible to make tags panel by meta box by jet engine ?
ty ^^
and i replaced it but nope !

i read other similar posts too.

i read other similar posts too.

Comment: Hi, I am assuming that JetEngine is a plugin that allows you to create Custom Post Types visually, please on the screen where you added the Custom Post Type, search for anything called taxonomy | taxonomies. Some plugins let you assign or create the relation at Custom Post Type Editor. Other plugins might have a dedicated custom taxonomy screen, where you can add a custom taxonomy or extend existing core ones like Tags and Categories. If you can provide some screenshots of where you registered the custom post type maybe I can tell you more.